# How do I create a recursive function that sums up digits?

Tags: c, recursion

I need to create a function that recursively adds up each digit in a large number.

For example, if the user inputs the number `143`, the function should return `1+4+3` which is `8`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `f(0) = 0; f(x | x>0) = f(x/10) + x % 10`. Now code it, you have everything.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/STotJB)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You basically just need to calculate %10 every time to get the last digit and recursively sum up all those results.

Here is an example:

```
int sum;

public int sumOfDigits(int number){
    if(number<10)
       return sum+number;
    else{
       sum += (number%10);
       return sumOfDigits(number/10);
    }
}
```

Comment: why recursion, just loop

`while (t != 0)
       {
          remainder = t % 10;
          sum       = sum + remainder;
          t         = t / 10;
       }`

Comment: crai - he asked for a recursive solution.

Comment: This solution isn't in C, and sum isn't initialized to 0

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that given a number, you can sum its digits by recursively summing the number without its last digit sum, and add the last digit. Calculating the last digit is simple `x%10`, and getting the number without the last digit is `x/10`. The base case when you hit 0 (you removed all digits) - return 0.

```
int sum_digits(int x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;
    return x%10 + sum_digits(x/10);
}
```

Comment: If negative numbers are an expected input, just add a wrapper function that checks if a number is negative and returns `sum_digits(-x)`

Comment: That works well aside from `sum_digits(- INT_MIN)`, yet doubt OP needs to solve that corner case.  UV

Comment: i actually need to change to addition or devision each time i call the function.
for example 143 ---> 1-4+3

Comment: You should probably open a new question about it, but assuming we have a function that calculates the length of a integer `num_len`, this is the recursive step in C to calculate what you asked: `return sum_digits(x/10) + (-1+2*(num_len(x)%2))*(x%10)` (we either add `x%10` or subtract `x%10` from our sum (`sum_digits(x/10)`) depending on the length of the number - adding when it's odd (like 143 - the 3 has a plus before it) and subtracting when it's even (14 -> 4 got a minus)